# connect signal (Qstring) whit slot (String) of 2 different class

Tags: c++, qt, signals, slot

i have 2 class : Class MaFentre and Code

code.h :

```
class Code : public QObject {

public :


explicit  Code(Q3DScatter *scatter);

    public slots:
 std::vector<point> readingData(std::string inputFileName);
}
```

MaFenetre.h :

```
class MaFenetre : public QWidget
{  Q_OBJECT
    public:
MaFenetre();
    private:
    QLineEdit *entry1;
}
```

Code.cpp :

```
std::vector<point> Code::readingData(std::string inputFileName){
// i read a file here
}
```

i created the Code class object in the constructor of the class MaFenetre

```
    Code *modifier = new Code(graph);
```

for making connection between slot and signal

```
QObject::connect(entry1, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),modifier, SLOT(readingDara(std::string inputFileName)))
```

i know the parameters must be of the same type , for that i try to code :

```
    QObject::connect(entry, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString.toStdString)),modifier, SLOT(readingDara(std::string inputFileName)))
```

but it doesnt work

Comment: Missing Q_OBJECT

Comment: I added it but still doesn't work

Comment: Also your connect is alk wrong. Check Qt docs/tutorials/examples for correct syntax. If you use old syntax (with SIGNAL and SLOT macros), prefer Qt Creator autocompletion to get it right. With new syntax, compiler should give error if you get it wrong, which is much nicer.

Comment: try using only `connect(...)` ? and a slot don't have toreturn `void` ?

Comment: i think the connect is correct , I've already used this syntax

Comment: Related point : Consider using the [new signal slot syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work ? Does the compiler throw and error or does it not work/not hit the slot when the signal is emitted ?

Comment: Also `entry1`  is a private member of the `MaFenetre` class, how are you going to access this member in your example code?

Comment: Compiler gives errors

Comment: the signal textchanged(QString) return the valeur of entry1 , also i created a method in class MaFentre for retunr vale of entry1  but i  don't know how to call a mehod in another class

Comment: You cannot do this with the old connect syntax. You have to change your `Code::readingData` so it takes a `QString` as an argument. If you use the new syntax, then you could use a lambda to convert the `QString` to `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

Your signal and slot arguments are not compatible.

You can do this workaround with the `lambda` function

```
 Code *modifier = new Code();
 MaFenetre * poMaFenetre = new MaFenetre();

 connect(poMaFenetre->Entry(), &QLineEdit::textChanged,
         [modifier](const QString & oText)
 {
     std::vector<int> data = modifier->readingData(oText.toStdString());
     // Handle data here...
 });
```

In the `MaFenetre`

```
class MaFenetre : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    MaFenetre() {entry1.reset(new QLineEdit());}
    QLineEdit *Entry() {return entry1.data();}
    private:
    QScopedPointer<QLineEdit> entry1;
};
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you want to do it you can explain to me

Comment: Your original connect can't work because of the parameter, I used the `lambda` function to hack the parameters. this way you don't have to change the `readingData` function argument to `QString`, and you have to get `QString` argument because this what `QLineEdit::textChange` is sending. please read about [signal slot new syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) read the lambda section too.

Comment: ok i will read about **signal slot new syntaxe** but pls ` {entry1.reset(new QLineEdit());}` , `{return entry1.data();}` i dont understand why You put these instructions next to contructor , And they mean what

Comment: I used the [QScopedPointer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscopedpointer.html) to avoid memory leak it will auto delete the `entry1` instance when it's out of scope , if you delete the instance of `entry1` by your self, you don't need that. sorry if it's confused you, it dosen't concern the signal slot syntax. It's just part of the code refactoring.

Comment: okay i test it in my program ; You can show me where I have to write each instruction

Answer (score 1):

Using signals and slots it's not the same as calling function and pass parameters.

At first signal and slot must have same parameters type, means they must be defined with same parameters. In your case you have to change your slot to fit possible signals. Also note that returned value is useless in case of slot invoking, so better way is to keep you reading function as is, move it to private area, and create wrapper slot:

```
void Code::readingDataSlot(QString inputFileName)
{
    std::vector<point> result = readingData( inputFileName.toStdString() );
    // Do what ever you need with result vector
}
```

and connect it to signal.

```
connect(entry1, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),modifier, SLOT(readingDataSlot(QString)));
```

Comment: I explain you my program : i have 2 method : readingData for read the contents of a file , and the method addData for to plot the contents of a file , to read the data in addData i type the following code :                  `std::vector<point> inputData = Code::readingData(name of to file);`   
                                                                                                                                         and in the contructor Code i put  : `addData() `

Comment: @Souhail sounds messy. My point is: slots should not return any value, because it's will unused.

Comment: How I can do it to run my program

Comment: In modern Qt, such "slots" belong as lambdas in the connect statement itself. Messing with separate slots for them is very much unproductive: humans have lots of trouble with lack of locality of reference. By spreading little, highly related bits of code all over the place, you're making the code harder to understand and maintain. Remember that a lot of software engineering has zilch to do with computers and engineering, but everything to do with psychology of cognition. We need to do a lot of work just so that we can keep comprehending ever more complex software.

Comment: @KubaOber yes lambdas could be good, but I prefer to avoid lambdas if it become bigger than just few lines. And I belive lambda maybe quite diffucult to understand for a begginers like topic starter.